# SQL Job Agent Service Account - Access is denied to run Powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run a PowerShell script via the command line via SQL Job.

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" "C:\Test\TestScript.ps1"
```

I am running the SQL Job from a SQL Server 2008 R2 server. Which permissions does the SQL Job Agent Service Account need to run a PowerShell script? Or is this a windows permission level, not a db permission?

EDIT:
This is the error I am getting
Executed as user: ****.

> The process could not be created for step 3 of job ## (reason: Access
>   is denied). The step failed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

### You have to call powershell.exe instead of the foldername

**Change this**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" "C:\test\testscript.ps1"
```

**To this**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "C:\test\testscript.ps1"
```

**Testing by creating the same jobstep**

[image]

**The original command**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" "C:\test\testscript.ps1"
```

**The error**

> Executed as user: ServiceAcc. The process could not be created for
>   step 1 of job .. (reason: Access is denied).  The step failed.

**Changing the command and running the job again**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "C:\test\testscript.ps1"
```

**Great success**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is that the SQL agent account has access to all of the drives/folders required for the operation.